How many Hungarians returned after the 1956 Uprising, and when?
As a result of the Hungarian Uprising of 1956, some 200,000 of its residents fled abroad, most of whom were eventually accepted as refugees.  Despite terminating the jobs and confiscating the property of those who had fled, the Soviet-aligned Hungarian government took a number of steps designed (at least in part) to entice the "dissidents", "counterrevolutionaries", or "fifty-sixers" to voluntarily return.  These measures started almost immediately after the end of the uprising and continued throughout the following decades.  Among them were the following:

In November 1956 it signed an agreement with Yugoslavia concerning voluntary repatriation of emigrés.
In November 1956 it resolved to establish a repatriation office in Vienna, which was eventually established with consent of the Austrian government in January 1957.
In December 1956 it offered a blanket amnesty to emigrés who returned by the end of March 1957.
In December 1956 it established a service bureau for Hungarians abroad wishing to repatriate.
In March 1957 it slightly loosened the conditions of the previously declared blanket amnesty and indicated that, following the original deadline, it would continue to accept amnesty applications, with decisions thenceforth being made on a case-by-case basis.
In August 1957, it established a new commission for the return of emigrés in Yugoslavia using an expedited procedure.
In October 1960, it invited "non-hostile" emigrés to apply for passports that would permit them to return temporarily to visit family members.
In or after 1963, it took further measures to allow emigrés and their children to visit Hungary temporarily for the purposes of study or tourism.
In 1988, it declared a further amnesty for those involved in the 1956 Uprising.
In 1989, it proclaimed a new republic and arranged for multiparty elections the following year. (Within a few years, the new government arranged monetary compensation for emigrés whose property had been seized.)

Each of the above-noted measures must have incentivized at least some of the refugees to return permanently to Hungary.  The institution and development of so-called "Goulash Communism" in the 1960s and 1970s, and the subsequent rise in standards of living, must have further contributed to the allure of repatriation.  I do have repatriation figures for certain limited time periods and countries of origin.  For example:

By March 1957, nearly 4000 Hungarians had voluntarily repatriated from Austria.
By December 1957, 2327 Hungarians had voluntarily repatriated from Yugoslavia.
By 1958, somewhere between 11,447 and 11,883 Hungarians had voluntarily repatriated through the Austrian repatriation office.

Many of the mesaures and all of the repatriation figures listed above are discussed in [1].  I am also personally acquainted with some emigrés who resettled in Hungary in the 1990s.
However, what I am missing is a more complete view of the number and source of repatriations.  Are there any sources that give a breakdown of repatriations by year across the period 1957 to 1989, and possibly beyond?  Do any such sources further note the countries of origin and the reasons for repatriation?  (The CIA produced some nice reports on repatriations to East Germany in the early 1950s, providing detailed statistics where available as well as analyses of the reasons for and effects of the repatriations [2, 3].  I'd be very interested in reading something similar for Hungary, albeit covering a longer time period.)

References:
[1] Baráth, Magdolna (2022).  "János Kádár’s government and the refugees of the Hungarian Revolution of 1956." The Exile History Review, Vol. 1. DOI: 10.31743/ehr.14613.
[2] Central Intelligence Agency (1954). "The effects of migrations into and out of East Germany on the labor situations in East and West Germany."  Economic Intelligence Report CIA/RR 30.
[3] Central Intelligence Agency (1956). "Migration from West Germany to East Germany 1952–1954"  Provisional Intelligence Report CIA/RR PR-150.
